# How do I get Calendar to stop emailing me reminders about Google Calendar events?

Tags: macos, calendar, google-calendar, alert

I get an excessive number of email reminders sent from Calendar when I have it enabled for my Google Calendar account. When I set a reminder on a Google Calendar event, Google properly sends me one email for events for which I choose to get an email. But Calendar on macOS sends me many, often sending 2 with the same time stamp, and even sometimes sends emails after the event has ended. How do I stop these?

[image: Sample of an event that has given many alerts]

Comment: Did you check the event itself in Calendar, see if it's piled up an irregular list of alerts/emails. Sometimes if you move an event, it will generate spurious alerts.

Comment: This happens with every event, actually

Comment: …which doesn't answer my question...

Comment: Yes, I've checked the event that caused the most recent flurry of alerts

Comment: Added a screenshot to the original post